# Failed tree-less parsing using python lark

Tags: python, lark-parser

I use [lark](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to parse lines of a log file. The log file contains some equations and I would like to extract the left hand side and right hand side of the equations and store them in a dictionary. However, in my context the parsing seems to be kind of slow. I accelerated the parsing by switching from the Earley algorithm to LALR(1) parsing, as suggested by the [lark tutorial](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_tutorial.html#step-2-lalr-1).
However, I would like to squeeze out the last bit of performance, by also [»going tree-less«](https://lark-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/json_tutorial.html#step-3-tree-less-lalr-1). Unfortunately, it does not work as expected. Consider the following MWE:

```py
from lark import Lark, Transformer

OPT = True

def parser() -> Lark:
    grammar = r"""
        equations: [equation ("," equation)*]
        equation: identifier "=" rhs
        identifier: CNAME
        rhs: num
           | vector
        vector: "[" [num ("," num)*] "]"
        num: SIGNED_NUMBER
        %import common.CNAME
        %import common.SIGNED_NUMBER
        %import common.WS
        %ignore WS
    """
    if OPT:
        eq_parser = Lark(grammar, start="equations", parser="lalr", transformer=ToDict)
    else:
        eq_parser = Lark(grammar, start="equations", parser="lalr")
    return eq_parser


class ToDict(Transformer):
    def equations(self, eqs):
        return {lhs: rhs for eq in eqs for lhs, rhs in eq.items()}

    def equation(self, eq):
        (ident, _rhs) = eq
        return {ident: _rhs}

    def rhs(self, num_vec):
        (num_vec,) = num_vec
        return num_vec

    def identifier(self, ident):
        (ident,) = ident
        return str(ident)

    def num(self, n):
        (n,) = n
        return float(n)

    def vector(self, vec):
        return list(vec)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    line = "a=3.14, b=[1.41, 1.732]"
    prsr = parser()
    if OPT:
        parsed = prsr.parse(line)
    else:
        parsed = ToDict().transform(prsr.parse(line))
    print(parsed)
```

If `OPT` is set to `False`, the expression `{'a': 3.14, 'b': [1.41, 1.732]}` is returned as expected. But if `OPT` is set to `True`, this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../mwe.py", line 55, in <module>
    parsed = prsr.parse(line)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/lark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lark/lark.py", line 625, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(text, start=start, on_error=on_error)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/lark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lark/parser_frontends.py", line 96, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(stream, chosen_start, **kw)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/lark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lark/parsers/lalr_parser.py", line 41, in parse
    return self.parser.parse(lexer, start)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/lark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lark/parsers/lalr_parser.py", line 171, in parse
    return self.parse_from_state(parser_state)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/lark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lark/parsers/lalr_parser.py", line 179, in parse_from_state
    state.feed_token(token)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/lark/lib/python3.10/site-packages/lark/parsers/lalr_parser.py", line 150, in feed_token
    value = callbacks[rule](s)
TypeError: ToDict.identifier() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ident'
```

What is the error message trying to tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass in an instance of the Transfomer class, not the class itself:

`transformer=ToDict()`

instead of

`transformer=ToDict`

Comment: silly me, how could I not see this 